# Incorrect money value from .NET saved through stored procedure (Sybase)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, sap-ase, currency

My .NET code inserts a decimal value to a money column in the database via a stored procedure. The stored procedure accepts this value as a money parameter. I'm expecting the value to be rounded at the 4th decimal place before it gets inserted. However, some values are saved as expected, while some are rounded up when it shouldn't. Refer to [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujldw.png).

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening? I already read Sybase ASE 15.7 documentation on converting to/from money, and all it says is that it's supposed to round (i.e. keep digit if next digit is 0-4, round up if next digit is 5-9) or round_to_even (if option is enabled; it's disabled in my DB), but these don't explain what happened in the screenshot. Another weird thing is that sometimes it rounds properly, other times it doesn't, and I can't find a pattern (yet).

I'm assuming that this is related to the driver we use to connect to Sybase because running the stored procedure directly does not result to the same issue. I'm just unable to find any resources online to support this assumption

Comment: Can you share the code of stored procedure? And also the data for which it rounded up properly and for which it did not.

Comment: It seems likes a logical bug in the stored procedure. Anyhow, why not round it off in .Net instead of an SP? It much convenient doing such tasks in .Net than SP.

Comment: @athar13, yes, that's a solution i suggested, but bosses (and myself) would still like to know why there's a difference in the first place. at the moment, there's no specific rounding code anywhere (.net and db). it's expected for sybase to automatically round the value when we insert a numeric(38,10) into money, but something's messing up the value if the sp call comes from .net.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, will get you sample values on monday. as for the core, it's a straightforward insert statement within the sp.  `create proc TableXCreate  ( @Amount money = null, @Amount2 money = null  )  as  begin  insert into TableX (Amount, Amount2)  values (@Amount, @Amount2)  end`